# Publish unsigned Cordova based iOS app on Ubuntu

Tags: ios, cordova, ubuntu, terminal

Is it possible to publish an **unsigned** Cordova based iOS app on Ubuntu? 
Currently I get this error after running `cordova build --release` from the terminal.

> CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'xcodebuild was not
>   found. Please install version 9.0.0 or greater from App Store'

My goal is to publish the **unsigned** .ipa and sign it later through *build.phonegap.com*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't.**

In order to build `.ipa` you need to open your project's `platform/ios` folder with XCode.
*In a word, you should run Mac OS or at least VM ware version.*